# How to change arcgis online mapview extent

Tags: javascript, gis, arcgis, arcgis-js-api, extent

Using the ArcGIS JavaScript API 4.0, I want to change ArcGIS webmap view when I clicked a list item.

I want to define different extent for extA, extB, extC, etc.

I have tried the code below but I couldn't get it.

```js
    require([ 
      "esri/views/MapView",
      "esri/WebMap",
      "esri/widgets/Compass",
   "esri/widgets/Search",
   "esri/widgets/BasemapToggle",
   "esri/widgets/Home",
      "esri/layers/FeatureLayer",
   "esri/geometry/Extent",
   "esri/geometry/SpatialReference",
      "dojo/dom-construct",
      "dojo/domReady!"
    ], function(
      MapView, WebMap, Compass, Search, BasemapToggle, Home, FeatureLayer, Extent, SpatialReference, domConstruct
    ) {

   
      var webmap = new WebMap({
        portalItem: { // autocasts as new PortalItem()
          id: "b3e185396c874f939265fcfc54d4909c"
        }
      });


      var view = new MapView({
        map: webmap,
        container: "viewDiv",
          extent: { // autocasts as new Extent()
            xmin: 29.00,
            ymin: 32.00,
            xmax: 42.00,
            ymax: 46.00,
            spatialReference: 4326
          }
      });

        document.getElementById("extA").addEventListener("click", function(){
   var extA = new Extent((25.77392578125, 38.03466796875, 31.300048828125, 42.9345703125, new SpatialReference({wkid:4326})), false);
    var viewupd = new MapView({
    map: webmap,
    container: "viewDiv",
    extent: extA
    });
      view: viewupd
  });
```

```html
<html lang="en" class="no-js demo">
 <head>  

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/main.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/esri/css/calcite/calcite.css">

  <script src="https://js.arcgis.com/4.0/"></script>
      
 </head>
  
  <body>
<div class="item">
   <div class="side">
      <ul class='menu'>
       <li id="extA"><a href="#">extent A</a></li>
       <li id="extB"><a href="#">extent B</a></li>
       <li id="extC"><a href="#">extent C</a></li>
       <li id="extD"><a href="#">extent D</a></li>
       <li id="extE"><a href="#">extent E</a></li>
      </ul>
 </div>
 <div class="side">
  <div id="viewDiv"></div>
 </div>
</div>
```

https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/latest/api-reference/esri-geometry-Extent.html

Answer (score 0):

[Use the `.setExtent` method](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/jshelp/intro_extents.html), e.g.

```
var extA = new Extent((25.77392578125, 38.03466796875, 31.300048828125, 42.9345703125, new SpatialReference({wkid:4326})), false);
WebMap.setExtent(extA );
```

Comment: Thx for respond but it didnt work. .setExtent method didn't work on latest arcgis jsapi. But I tried view.extent = extA; and it worked ;)  Thx again.

Comment: Geez, you're right. That's going to break a bunch of my viewers :\ Thanks for the tip!